# Change button in datagrid edit mode with templateselector

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to change the behavior of a button in an `DataGridTemplateColumn` by `CellTemplateSelector` if the row is newly added or in edit mode.
The button should normaly labeld "DELETE" but when in edit mode it should be labeld "INSERT" and call an other method.

Here what I have found on other examples. But I don't figure out, how to access the DataGrid(Row) in the `DataGridButtonSelector`.

in my XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DataGridButtonSelector x:Key="DataGridButtonSelector" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<DataGrid x:Name="dgMassnahmen" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,10,10.667,46.667" ColumnWidth="SizeToCells" RowHeight="62" RowEditEnding="dgMassnahmen_RowEditEnding" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" AddingNewItem="dgMassnahmen_AddingNewItem">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="insertTemplate">
                <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Content="Einfügen" Click="Button_Click_2" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=DataContext, Converter={StaticResource GridViewButtonVisibilityConverter}}"></Button>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="deleteTemplate">
                <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Content="Entfernen" Click="btnDelete_Click" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=DataContext, Converter={StaticResource GridViewButtonVisibilityConverter}}">
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
...
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="1*" Header="" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DataGridButtonSelector}">
...
```

and my DataGridButtonSelector.cs:

```
class DataGridButtonSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{

    public DataTemplate insertTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate deleteTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
    // HERE I STUCK!
            if (//THE ROW IS IN EDIT MODE (AND SELECTED))
                return
                    element.FindResource("insertTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else
                return
                    element.FindResource("deleteTemplate") as DataTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Set breakpoint on the first line in `SelectTemplate` and observe parameters. This should give you a clue in such cases. Maybe `container` is of the type you can use. Or maybe traversing up visual tree will provide you with one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use a trigger and set whatever you want in it:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="agggsdf" ></TextBlock>
                            <Button Name="f"></Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>  
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=IsEditing}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="f" Property="Content" Value="remove"></Setter>
                                    <Setter TargetName="f" Property="Style">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                                            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Button_Click"></EventSetter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=IsEditing}" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="f" Property="Content" Value="insert"></Setter>
                                <Setter TargetName="f" Property="Style">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                                            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="f_Click"></EventSetter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>

                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi. thanks. Works, but its not complete. Your code change the Content Property, but i need to change the binded Click Event too. if content = insert, then call  Click1, if ciontent = delete then Click2. I searched for that in internet and see that there must be Style EventSetter in the xaml.. but where ? :)

It where very nice by you, if you could give a snippet for the template selector. I think the XAML should only be visual, and the logic in cs.

what bad english :)

Comment: edited the code. take a look at commands sometime, then you could do something like this: <Button Command="{Binding MyCommandInDataContext}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=IsEditing}" />. and then you only have 1 method which does different things depending on whether commandparameter is true(editing) or false(not editing)